# Visual Studio Code not recognising Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am following the [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) to use Visual Studio Code as an external editor for Unity to the letter, but VS Code does not get autocompletion for Unity classes and methods. I have tried installing C# and Unity extensions but alas...

```
using UnityEngine // not allowed
class Rocket extends MonoBehaviour // not allowed
```

How can I get code completion for Unity C# in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Why bother with VS code? Even if you're on a Mac, now you can use VS on it (get Community for the free license version ofc).

Comment: I use VS2012 and I can't have a project with '#' character on its name, if I do it won't autocomplete, maybe it could be this.

Comment: @Galandil I like VS Code more because it's blazing fast, and has a very clear git interface. VS seems monolithic by comparison. What's the advantage of VS over Monodevelop?